# Are Tokusatsu series questions allowed to be asked on Anime & Manga.SE?

Tags: discussion

Pretty much like the title says, should questions about Tokusatsu series (Kamen Rider, Ultraman, Sentai series, etc) be included/can be asked in or should it have its own subdomain such as ***tokusatsu.stackexchange.com***?

Comment: To clarify tokusatsu and related dramas are off topic because they are *live-action*, but animated shows based on or derived from tokusatsu (e.g. the Ultraman manga) or drama are perfectly fine. We are also not apart of Stack Overflow. Any relation is merely a coincidence.

Comment: Sorry, edited it. Thanks for mentioning it. My mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Tokusatsu* shows are by definition live-action shows. Live-action as a medium is broadly off-topic here. Specific live-action shows might still be allowed if they're based on an anime, manga, or other similarly on-topic source material. We've allowed questions like "What are the differences between manga X and its live-action adaptation?". In practice, that means that most questions about the live action versions of many series e.g. [Hana Yori Dango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hana_Yori_Dango) or [GTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Teacher_Onizuka) would be allowed here. *Tokusatsu* shows based on manga are no different, so e.g. [Ambassador Magma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambassador_Magma) is basically fine since it was originally a manga.

However, if there's no anime or manga version, then it's clearly off-topic here. If there is an anime or manga version, but your question is highly specific to the live-action version, it's also probably not a good fit here. For instance, if you're asking about a plot point which is only part of the live-action, it probably doesn't belong here. We haven't had to work out the details here because it hasn't been a problem thus far, but as a general guideline I'd suggest avoiding anything which only makes sense in the context of the live-action version.

Most of the series you mentioned do have manga versions. Kamen Rider has at least 10 different manga series which cover most of the original and quite a bit more. Ultraman has several manga versions as well including a [sequel to the TV series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraman_(manga)). The Super Sentai series has a few manga versions as well. So a lot of questions about these very popular *tokusatsu* series technically fit on this site, but they aren't universally on-topic.

There are several other SE sites which probably cover more about *tokusatsu* shows than we do. Most of these shows would be on-topic on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). They'd also be on-topic on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). They might be better places than here to ask those questions.